# Why does python string remove() function run twice every time in Visual Studio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a program remove strings from a list by index value, but it keeps running `remove()` twice at a time.

For example trying to remove the second item from a list of identical strings:

```
list = ['banana', 'banana', 'banana']
index = 1
list.remove(list.pop(index))
```

then list only contains `['banana']`.

And:

```
list = ['apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana']
index = 1
list.remove(list.pop(index))
```

returns
`['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'banana']`

so it seems that for whatever reason the removal is running twice but the `list.pop(index)` only runs the first time. It still occurs when I break the `list.pop(index)` into a separate variable

Is this possibly a bug with visual studio code? I don't see why the `remove()` function would run twice every time.

Comment: `.pop()` removes the item already.

Comment: Try: *del list[index]* or *list.pop(index)* There's no need for *remove()*

Comment: Why are you calling `pop()`?  What is the purpose?  If you want to remove a specific index from the list, use `del list[index]` as @DarkKnight said.  Or, if you're a beginner and you don't know about `del`, still the obvious way is to call `list.remove(list[index])`.  I don't understand why you are calling `pop()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point here is that you access the desired element using `.pop()` method that itself removes/pops the element at the given index ( default the last index ) and return it.

so this `list.remove(list.pop(index))` , executes from in to out first it applies the `list.pop(index)` part , that as we mention above removes the element at index `index` and return it , then the returned value of element passed to the `list.remove(value)` so it by it's rule go and remove the first occurance of this element in list so you face this behaviour that seems like `twice run` and that's it.

so if your target to remove element at index `index` of the list , you can do this either by `list.remove(list[index])` , or `list.pop(index)`

```
list = ['banana', 'banana', 'banana']
index = 1
list.remove(list[index])
# list become ['banana', 'banana']
```

or

```
list = ['banana', 'banana', 'banana']
index = 1
list.pop(index)
# list become ['banana', 'banana']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the item twice.

In [DataStructures](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) you can see that pop() removes the item and **returns** it. Then you are passing that returned item to remove() function. So yes, you are removing it twice.

If you use pop() the list will be modified inplace.

```
list = ['banana', 'banana', 'banana']
list.pop(1)
print(list)
>>> ['banana', 'banana']
```

If you want, you can capture the pop value.

```
list = ['banana', 'banana', 'banana']
x = list.pop(1)
print(list)
>>> ['banana', 'banana']

print(x)
>>> 'banana'
```